# Loss of Quality when merging PDF with pdfpages

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, texi2dvi

I have a quality problem when merging one-sided PDFs into multiple page PDFs using the `pdfpages` package. The initial PDFs consist of scanned sides of books.

I create the LaTeX-File inside R and compile it with the texi2dvi() function. However the problems occur as well when I run it from LateX directly. Therefore I assume that it is a LaTeX-issue.
The merging itself works fine with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6
\begin{document}
\includepdf{0_00018_Q_1920.pdf}
\newpage
\includepdf{0_00018_Q_1923.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The issues I have are some random black bars over some parts of the document so that former black-on-white text then appears as white-on-black, as well as a general loss of quality like the exaggeration of small scan artifacts. It reminds me of the result when you copy something and you reduce the brightness of the copier...
[image: Example of the difference in Quality before and after merging. Left ist the original and right the result after merging.]
Btw: Example of the difference in Quality before and after merging. Left ist the original and right the result after merging.

Edit: I think there are two things going wrong. One is the these black bars, that only occur with certain documents. The other one is a difference in the anti-aliasing of the pdfs... The merged ones simply have no anti-aliasing and seem therefore to be of worse quality.
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/l/DOGs9XVCBVOzWLBqtbe0Ro) is the example file (left side of the image) which looks good before merging...

Still no ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Where do the PDF files come from? Can't they be possibly protected against manipulation? Have you tried another PDF viewer than Acrobat?

Comment: The Files come from a Scanner, in their Properties it says: PDF created with: **LuraDocument PDF v.2.53**, and they are PDF **Version 1.6** (which already caused a problem before, and was solved by the 3rd line of the LaTeX - code).The documents are not protected against manipulation, but are marked as **"Archive"**...

Comment: Does this only happen with `texi2dvi` or also when you use `pdflatex`/`lualatex` directly?

Comment: It occurs with `texi2dvi` and also when I run it directly (I use `pdfLateX` in teXworks).

Comment: Please provide an example PDF file from the scanner to analyze the problem. The program pdfTeX is not able to change the bitmap data, they are just copied. Also test with different PDF viewers for the case this is an PDF viewer issue.

Comment: I have already tested this with different viewers and also printed the result file and it is always the same... But I have have edited the question and provided a file from the scanner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scanner does not store the scan as simple bitmap. It uses several bitmaps that are combined using soft masks and the optical content group (OCG) feature. The latter causes the trouble, because some data are stored in the catalog of the PDF document, not in the page or its resources. The TeX engines pdfTeX and LuaTeX only store the page with its resources, when importing a PDF page from another document. The catalog data cannot easily merged. A merging of several OCG settings (from the importing document and from imported documents) is beyond the scope of pdfTeX.

There is no easy workaround, because pdfTeX does not tell, which OCGs are used in the document and there is no access to the catalog of the imported document.

For following special example works for pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15:

```
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}  
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6
\pdfcatalog{
  /OCProperties<<
      /D <<
      /OFF []
      /Order [28 0 R 29 0 R]
      /RBGroups []
    >>
    /OCGs [28 0 R 29 0 R]
  >>
}   
\begin{document}
\includepdf{0_00018_Q_1920.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I get a document, which is displayed correctly with AR9/Linux. But the contents of the catalog stuff are taken manually from the document `0_00018_Q_1920.pdf` and the object referneces `28 0 R` and `29 0 R` are taken from a previous run of the test file. `\pdfobjcompresslevel` prevents putting objects into compressed object streams. Then looking for `/OCGs [...]` in a text viewer revealed the needed numbers. These depend on the document, when the page is included. Thus this workaround is not practical at all.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I would never have gotten to this point. It worked also for the same file on Win7 (and some random others). So if I get you right, you found the numbers `28` and `29` by trial and error and we can't get them out of the file beforehand?
Could you imagine there being any way of somehow "reducing" the PDFs before reading the LaTeX routine or merging them into a single bitmap?

Comment: @simoet The numbers are unknown beforehand. Some tools such as `pdfimages` can extract the embedded bitmap data from a PDF file. Then you can experiment with the result.